# Laravel GroupBy and OrderBy problem with sorting order

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by

I have table two tables. One with numbers

[image]

and second one with comments.

[image]

And I woud like to take latest comment from each telephone group and have collection of unique telephone number and latest comment to it soted by comments latest.

I do try something like this but the results no good.
I go unique number from group but this number got oldest comment. I need number and latest comment to it.
Thank you.
[image]

Comment: it's better to post as text instead of image.

Comment: Please add code snippet instead of posting an image. To insert code snippet the shortcut key combo is `Ctrl+k`. Also what is the foreign key that is relating these tables?

Comment: Yes, the foreign key is commentable_id in table comments

Answer (score 0):

is better to use eloquent eager loading tho, with this way, your output is more organized, use dd() to see your output.

```
public function index () {
    $telephones = Telephone::with(['comments' => function ($q) {
        $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }])
        ->orderBy('telephones.created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(3);
}
```

this way, the comments is sorted first before attach to telephones.

Comment: Part of it it works, but I do not have access to comments table, can I now glue comments it to it and display only numbers with the latest comments? Foreign key "commentable_id" Thank you

Comment: @Marcin - is the comments table a morph table?

Comment: I think no, is not morph table but not sure for 100%

Comment: are you able to show model class for Telephone ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use subquery for have result what you want.

Try use somthing like that:

```
$subQuery = "
        select * from comments where created_at in (select max(created_at) from comments group by commentable_id)
    ";

    $query = DB::table('telephones')->leftJoin(
        DB::raw(
            "($subQuery) as comments"
        ), function(Builder $query) {
        $query->on('telephones.id','=', 'comments.commentable_id');
    })->select(['number', 'comment']);

    $result = $query->get();
```

You can change this query for model

Answer (score 0):

After checking and searching this code works fine for me in the way I want.
It give me one Telephone number with latest comment.

```
 public function index()
{
    $telephones = Telephone::join('comments', function ($join) {
        $join->on('telephones.id', '=', 'comments.commentable_id');
    })
        ->select('*')
        ->whereIn('comments.id', function($q){
            $q->select(DB::raw('MAX(comments.id) FROM comments GROUP BY commentable_id'));
        })
        ->latest('comments.created_at')
        ->paginate(3);
```

Thank you